# Draw a bitmap with python from a numpy matrix

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I tried to draw a simple 10x10 black image with a single red pixel at the 8,8 coordinate.

This was my attempt:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

foo = np.zeros([10,10,3])
foo[8,8] = [255,0,0] # Draw a red pixel
img = Image.fromarray(foo, 'RGB')
img.save('out.png')
```

Sadly for some reason the entire image stays black (enlarged):

[image]

When printing "foo" the [255,0,0] entry is there, so I am confused on what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the data type of the numpy array to **int8**.

So you would have

```
foo = np.zeros([10,10,3], dtype=np.int8)
```